# Android Dev: AlarmManager Reschedule and Service

Tags: android

please refer to 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935573/android-dev-timertask-and-phone-sleep-weirdness-maybe) for the issue i was facing....as suggested by the person who replied to my problem + what my additional research showed is that i need to use AlarmManager to solve my sleep & timertask issue...since, i have started changing the existing code to utilize PendingIntent along with AlarmManager with: `Thread thr = new Thread(null, mTask, "ServiceName");` in the service...

after reading the AlarmManager documentation several times, i dont know how to reschedule a AlarmManager... im working on a Profile Switcher application, which will various run intervals (like i described in my problem thread)...

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: currently, im looking into creating a one-shot alarm, and then once that one-shot is about to expire, create a new one with the new updated interval...

Answer (score 5):

> i dont know how to reschedule a AlarmManager

Use `cancel()` to remove an existing alarm, and use `set()` or any of the other `set...()` methods to schedule alarms. To "reschedule" alarms, you cancel the old and create the new.

Comment: does this work all the time? sometimes I use cancel and set a new time for my pendingIntent... it does not work or the alarm is triggerred 10mins later

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same **intentString** and the same **request code**, your alarms will be overwritten.

In your intent, you can use the following flag:

```java
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

```java
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notification.getId(), new Intent(intentString), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

long startDateTimeMillis = notification.getDateTime().toDateTime().getMillis();

MyApplication.alarmManager().setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    startDateTimeMillis,
                    pendingIntent);
```

Related to the alarm itself, you can use the methods setExact() or set() and you can search about them to check which one fits you better.